# How to push specific commit of branch to other branch after many commits are already done on both branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, push, commit

I have two remote branches `master` and `dev`. I have committed one change to `master` and after that other commits are done. In second branch many changes are committed by other developers.
Problem : I want to push one earlier commit of `master` to `dev` branch.

Please give solution.

`git push origin cdadasdv5676asdvvfavsd67868vasdsavvs:dev` is not working for me.

**Note : I am using above command from `dev` branch.

Comment: FYI. I have merged all changes of **`dev`** branch to **`master`**. Still above command is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Git's *cherry pick* function. It will apply a single commit from one branch to a different branch. It will not do a merge, since in your situation (the branches have diverged), a merge will not work.

Here's what you should do:

```
# Check out the dev branch: 
git checkout dev

# Cherry pick the commit from the master branch
# I assume that `cdadasdv5676asdvvfavsd67868vasdsavvs` is the hash of the commit you want to apply to dev: 
git cherry-pick cdadasdv5676asdvvfavsd67868vasdsavvs
```

That's it. Please note that using a Git UI client like SourceTree makes this a lot easier.

More info on this can be found here:

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick
- https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-cherry-pick-changes-with-git